# In Julia Flux, I keep getting the error LoadError: Mutating arrays is not supported, but I don't see where I am mutating an array

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am new to Julia and for some reason I can't get this very simple code to work. No matter what I try, I get the error `LoadError: Mutating arrays is not supported`. I understand that this error occurs when I mutate an array during the course of optimization so that the code is no longer differentiable. I clearly do not understand Julia enough to see where I am doing this.

If it helps the error seems to be occurring in the line `for d in dataset`.

```
using Statistics
using Flux: onehotbatch, onehot, onecold, crossentropy, throttle
using Flux
using Base.Iterators:repeated
using Plots:heatmap
using ImageView:imshow

images = Flux.Data.MNIST.images()[1:10]
labels = Flux.Data.MNIST.labels()[1:10]

heatmap(images[4], color=:grays, aspect_ratio=1)

X = float.(reshape.(images, :))
encode(x) = onehot(x, 0:9)
Y = encode.(labels)

m = Chain(Dense(28^2, 32, relu), Dense(32, 10), softmax)

loss(x, y) = crossentropy(m(x), y)
opt = ADAM()

accuracy(x, y) = mean(onecold(m(x)) .== onecold(y))

dataset = zip(X, Y)

print(size(X))

evalcb = () -> @show(loss(X, Y))

print("Training...")
# Flux.train!(loss, params(m), dataset, opt, cb=throttle(evalcb, 5));
for d in dataset
    print(d[2])
    gs = gradient(params(m)) do
        l = loss(d...)
    end
    update!(opt, params(m), gs)
end
```

Comment: Your code runs, with `using Flux: update!`. Perhaps you have an old version of something? Try `] activate --temp` and then `add Flux Zygote` to get a fresh copy of everything.

Comment: Okay if it is package related, I should mention I am running this through the REPL on VSCode using the Julia extension. Could this have something to do with it? I'll try to run the code in the terminal and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I did have an old version of Flux (but not that old). I had to uninstall and reinstall Julia to install the new version of Flux.